# display rel attribute of div inside another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i want to display the value of rel attribute of my div inside another div whose id  is #num , right now i can alert the value but i want to display inside the #div, how can we do that ?
i have already tried to append it by this ($theValue).appendTo("#destination");
but it does not work.

Below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $(".key").on("click",function(){
    var $theValue=$(this).attr("rel");
    alert($theValue);
  });

});
```

Comment: Show the problem with a fiddle or any other way of showing the problem.. anyway, what about doing "$('yourDiv').html($theValue)"?????

Answer (score 0):

You can use `append` with `createTextNode` like as-

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $(".key").on("click",function(){
    var $theValue=$(this).attr("rel");
   $("#destination").append(document.createTextNode($theValue));
   // alert($theValue);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do take note the difference between .append() and .appendTo()

> The .append() and .appendTo() methods perform the same task. The major
>   difference is in the syntax-specifically, in the placement of the
>   content and target. With .append(), the selector expression preceding
>   the method is the container into which the content is inserted. With
>   .appendTo(), on the other hand, the content precedes the method,
>   either as a selector expression or as markup created on the fly, and
>   it is inserted into the target container

As quoted from: http://api.jquery.com/appendto/

I believe you want .append instead.